# Top-N elements in a table - Database Design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm currently developing an e-commerce site in Rails and I need to present a top 10 list of products and top 10 list of suppliers. 
What is the best or recommended way of modeling a Top N list of various tables?

I was considering three options:

- Storing the ranking position in the Product and Supplier tables and then retrieving the first 10
- Using two tables: ProductTop10 and SupplierTop10 with a 1 to n association (ProductTop10 has_many Products and Product belongs_to ProductTop10).
- Using two new tables: ProductRankingEntry and SupplierRankingEntry with a 1 to 1 association, limiting the number of rows to 10 (ProductRankingEntry belongs_to Product and Product has_one ProductRankingEntry).

but since I'm not very experienced with this issues, I'd love to hear from what others would do.

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

PS: I hope this is the right channel to discuss this matters. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option would be the best option to go with. Database now a days are smarter in sorting and limiting the rows. It has minimum efforts and resources required. The other two option will make it difficult to maintain once the application source code scales out. Also, it means more operations per user which could affect the performance at later stages of development.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think I'll try that approach. One last thing: would you keep this number updated for every table entry (100 entries - 100 positions) or just set to null all entries that didn't make it to the top 10? The table is created manually by the administrators.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you cant figure out at runtime which are max 10. Databases are very good at sorting them.